# Regex - conditional match for hyphened appendices

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm dealing with 8 character jobnames that must follow convention, but I want to allow additional characters if appended with a hyphen.

I have come up with this:

```
\w{2}YYY\w{3}(?(-).*|\b)
```

Which matches correctly:

```
XXYYY001 >> match

XXYYY001-TEST >> match

XXYYY001123  >> no match
```

This seems cumbersome however, so I just wanna know the most efficient expression.

EDIT:  Thanks Wiktor, your answer worked.

And to take it one step further: If I wanted to use a variable for YYY?

Comment: That regex never would run on JS. Are you sure you have put the right one?

Comment: Also what are allowed character after hyphen?

Comment: Have you considered using `indexOf` to find the index of the hyphen, then `substring` to get the end part? It would probably be much easier to read and maybe less brittle.

Comment: What kind of additional characters do you want to "allow"? If word chars only, use [`\b\w{2}YYY\w{3}(?:-\w+)?\b`](https://regex101.com/r/qWZUJV/1).

Comment: @revo dang, yur right...just tried plugging it in

Answer (score 0):

Like this.

explanation:

- `^` matches beginning of string
- `\w{2}YYY\w{3}` is the part you wrote. Matches main pattern
- `(\-.*)` matches a dash, followed by anything (including nothing. see test #4)
- `?` Means the previous match can occur zero or one times

```js
const pattern =  /^\w{2}YYY\w{3}(\-.*)?$/;

const strings = [
  'XXYYY001',
  'XXYYY001XXXTEST',
  'XXYYY001-TEST',
  'XXYYY003-',
  'FARFXXYYY003',
  'FARFXXYYY003-TEST'
];

strings.forEach(string => {
  let conforms = pattern.test(string);
  console.log(string,conforms);
});
```